# Parsley.js submit form with failed validation

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I am using two groups in Parlsey.js, one for warnings and one for critical errors. The form should still submit if warnings fail, but not submit if critical errors fail.

I've tried using `$('form').off('form:validate');` which i saw on another post, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

Ideally, I would like to only prevent the form submission if the critical group fails, but I doubt Parsley.js supports this. However, it seems there should be a way to tell Parsley.js to always submit the form regardless of it being valid or not. I could then register a submit handler to check only the critical group and prevent submission if it fails.

I can't find anything in the documentation to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no documented way to do this.

You could intercept the `submit` event, call Parsley to do the validation of your two groups, and if you are satisfied with the result, then call `$('.your-form').parsley()._submit()`.

As the name starts with `_`, it's meant to be a private method though. Also, `_submit` triggers another 'submit' event, so you need to ignore it ([like in this code](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/src/parsley/form.js#L23-L24)).

FWIW, Parsley aims to go beyond builtin HTML5 validations **while still being compatible with them**. What you want to do actually goes against the HTML5 standard, so it's quite reasonable that it's not "easy" to do.

Comment: Yes, I realize this an unusual use case, but we want to allow the user to save a "draft" even if it has these non critical warnings, yet still display the warnings to the user. It sounds like Parsley might not be the best solution given the unusual requirements.

Comment: One note, using `$('.your-form').parsley()._submit()` resulted in an infinite loop. I ended up calling the native JS `submit()` method on the native `DOM` element of the form (instead of the jQuery element)

Comment: Oh, right. You had to also check if the submit even was from Parsley (as [in this code](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/src/parsley/form.js#L23-L24), sorry)